# what does $Φ ^ {-1}$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a part of a statistics question I am given  $Φ ^ {-1}(0.9377)=1.536$ but I don't know what this  $Φ ^ {-1}$ means and how he got 1.536 and from where. any help is much appreciated thank you.

Comment: $\Phi^{-1}\left(\int_{-\infty}^z\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}dt\right)=z$ for $z\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in statistics, $\Phi(x)$ is used to denote the Cumulative distribution function of standard normal random variable (Normal random variable with mean 0 and variance 1).

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $\Phi(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$.

Now, $\Phi^{-1}(0.9377) =1.536 $ means that    $ \ \ \  0.9377 = \mathbb{P}(X \leq 1.536)$

Answer (score 2):

It's the inverse of the standard normal distribution, i.e. which value of $X$ yields $F(x)=.9377$. You cannot get a closed form solution for the inverse (not even for the CDF!) but numerically you can get good approximations

Comment: @Stacker Correct; $\Phi$ is the CDF, $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse thereof.